# ¿Es posible seleccionar todos los campos de una base de datos excepto unos pocos?

Tags: php, mysql, json

He estado buscando y no lo encuentro , pero me he encontrado que en una consulta mysql , necesito seleccionar casi todo el contenido menos 3 elementos , la cuestión es que son casi 20 columnas.
Se que por php se puede no mostrar esos campos , pero la salida la hago por medio de php y lo transformo en una salida de json y quería ahorrarme el hacer un posible engorroso código php pudiendo ahorrarlo desde la base mysql.

Yo he optado por seleccionar campo por campo , pero *¿Se puede hacer de una forma más elegante?*

**Un ejemplo :**

```
SELECT  b.gorro , b.pierna_derecha , b.pierna_izquierda , b.brazo_derecho , b.brazo.izquierdo ,...
FROM batman AS b
```

*¿En mysql existe una forma de seleccionar todos menos unos campos en concreto.?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392126/how-to-select-all-columns-in-sql-except-one-column) hay una respuesta en ingles que trata el mismo tema. Al parecer no se puede hacer de forma elegante, sino mas bien siguiendo una serie de "trucos" que por lo que vi generan desgastes en la performance y legibilidad de la consulta.

Mi consejo: tomate el tiempo de escribir las casi 20 columnas, tanto sql como quien vea el código más tarde te lo van a agradecer.

Comment: Entendido pero http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea es el link porque la que me pasas es un `duplicate` , aunque me vale de todas formas , gracias.

Comment: No me había dado cuenta de lo del duplicate. Me alegro que te haya servido! Saludos!

Comment: Además si luego añades columnas tienes que revisar todos los `select` que hace consultas por descarte, para descartar las nuevas columnas añadidas.

Comment: Excelente detalle!

Answer (score 0):

Realmente si que puedes hacerlo. Imagínate que tienes esta tabla creada:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons(
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  gorro varchar(255),
  pierna_derecha varchar(255),
  pierna_izquierda varchar(255),
  brazo_derecho varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO Persons VALUES(1,'gorro', 'pierna derecha', 'pierna izq', 'brazo dcho');
```

Y quieres omitir las columnas `pierna_derecha` y `pierna_izquierda` de la tabla `Persons` al hacer la select. Harías lo siguiente:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), 'pierna_derecha,pierna_izquierda', '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Persons' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'tuBaseDeDatos'), ' FROM Persons');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Ten en cuenta que tendrías que cambiar `tuBaseDeDatos` por tu base de datos real.

Answer (score 0):

Si ese `select` quieres que php no tenga que pensar, sino que simplemente le llegue de la base de datos correctamente, una opción que tienes es usar las vistas. Creas una vista `SELECT * FROM tuTabla` una vez creada, mySql te habrá cambiado el * por cada uno de los campos, quita los campos que no quieras mostrar.